# How do I raise a variable randomly between 20% and 30%?

Tags: netlogo

I have turtles defined by their **wealth** and every 30 ticks i want to "spend" 20%-30% of their wealth (like the spendings of a family). How do i set the new wealth **randomly** **between** **20%-30%** of my old wealth?

Comment: please post some code to improve chances of answers

Answer (score 2):

`random-float 0.1` will generate a random number in the range 0 to 0.1. So you can do something like `let spend 0.2 + random-float 0.1` will generate an appropriate number and assign it to a variable named spend. You can then do `set wealth spend * wealth`, which will reduce the wealth accordingly. Note that spending 20-30% will set their new wealth at 70-80% of their old wealth. If you want to end up with 20-30, you will need to have the spend higher.